# Difference in js native .value vs jQuery .val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a quick question about the difference in JavaScript's native element.value vs jQuery's $(element).val();

I have created a BB editor in AngularJS and this is where my question came from.

Here is the code for my directive:

```
bbApp.directive('bbEdit', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'tpl/editor.html',
    link: function(scope) {
            scope.tagType = '';
            var el = document.querySelector('#bbeditor');

            scope.wrap = function(type) {
                scope.tagType = type;

                var str = el.value.toString();
                var selection = str.slice(el.selectionStart, el.selectionEnd);

                if( scope.noWrapTags.indexOf(scope.tagType) == -1 && selection == "" ) {
                    alert('Please select text to format');
                    return false;
                }

                if( scope.allowedTags.indexOf(scope.tagType) == -1 ) {
                    alert('Sorry, that formatting option is not available');
                    return false;
                }

                var strArr = str.split("");

                if( scope.noWrapTags.indexOf(scope.tagType) != -1 ) {
                    strArr.splice(el.selectionStart,selection.length, "["+ scope.tagType +"]");
                } else {
                    strArr.splice(el.selectionStart,selection.length, "["+ scope.tagType +"]"+selection+"[/"+ scope.tagType +"]");
                }


                el.value = strArr.join("");

            }

          }

}});
```

I am accessing the element like so: `var el = document.querySelector('#bbeditor');`

then getting the value: `var str = el.value.toString();`

But when I attempt to do this using jQuery's .val() it's not working properly.

The way it is currently written, the app will wrap whatever highlighted text in the appropriate custom bb tag.

But when I access the value of the textarea like this:

```
var el = angular.element(element).find('textarea');
var str = el.val().toString();
```

I get the text value but my string manipulation simply wraps the entire value of the textarea with the bb tag as opposed to wrapping just the text highlighted by the user.

Is it even worth the hassle to use jQuery for this? Is my use of document.QuerySelector() okay?

I was just wanting to use what features are available in Angular, and obviously in my directive I can access element. But the jQuery .val() is not working the same as native .value.

Any explanation/advice would be appreciated. I am new to Angular.

My app is working, but I am just wondering if there is a different way I should be doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.querySelector` returns the first element that matches.  jQuery's `.find` method returns an array of matching elements.

Besides that, `.value` isn't returning the selected text, you are using `var selection = str.slice(el.selectionStart, el.selectionEnd)` to get the selected text.

If your code works in javascript, I'd leave it as such. There isn't a compelling reason to convert it to jQuery (IMHO).  You won't find anything that makes things overwhelmingly easier -- in this case.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I know .value isn't returning my highlighted text lol. Guess I could explain myself a bit better ha.

Thanks for the advice and info.

So if .find returns an array of matching elements something more like 
el[0].val() would be closer to the mark?

Just curious. I'm gonna take your advice and leave it as is since it's working.

Comment: Hmm.. Well, sorry, jQuery's .val() would have returned the value of the first element in the array, so that would have worked, but the selection code might have been wrong as `el.selectionStart` may not since el is an array and jQuery doesn't have a selectionStart property.  `el[0]` would return the first DOM element, so `el[0].selectionStart` should have been ok.  Hard to say without seeing your jQuery attempt as to say why it wasn't working.